# shared preference displays the old value in release mode

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-sharedpreference

Shared pref value in release mode shows the old value sometimes,
during the my testing it stores the value and can get the new value that I stored just to make sure but after closing application and opening it again, sometimes it shows the the old value, which I stored befoe new one.

here is example of my code:
to store and get value:

```
 void setToken(String userToken) async {
 var sharedPreferences = await shared;
 sharedPreferences.setString("$_token", userToken);
 print("token is: " +sharedPreferences.getString("$_token").toString());
 }
 
 Future getToken() async {
 var sharedPreferences = await shared;
 sharedPreferences.reload();
 String value = sharedPreferences.getString("$_token");
 print("your token: $value");
 return value;
  }
```

The result message:

in first store ( getting first token):
`token is: eyJhbG.....Ai-A`

Second token storing:
`token is: eyJhbG....oKk`

And after reopening app, I get the 1st token
`your token: eyJhbG.....Ai-A`

Is there anyone that faced the same issue?

Comment: Maybe you need to clear the session and then add your updated token

Answer (score 0):

Please copy-paste the below code:

```
 void setToken(String userToken) async {
 var sharedPreferences = await shared;
 sharedPreferences.setString("my_token", userToken);
 print("token is: " +sharedPreferences.getString("my_token").toString());
 }
 
 Future getToken() async {
 var sharedPreferences = await shared;
 sharedPreferences.reload();
 String value = sharedPreferences.getString("my_token");
 print("your token: $value");
 return value;
  }
```

Comment: $_token is string variable, I just didn't mention it

Answer (score 0):

please paste this solution in your code

```
 void setToken(String userToken) async {
 var sharedPreferences = await shared;
 sharedPreferences.setString("$_token", userToken);
 print("token is: " +sharedPreferences.getString("$_token").toString());
 }
 
 Future getToken() async {
 var sharedPreferences = await shared;
 String value = sharedPreferences.getString("$_token");
 print("your token: $value");
 return value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, this might work:

```
void setToken(String userToken) async {
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 sharedPreferences.setString("my_token", userToken);
 print("token is: " +sharedPreferences.getString("my_token").toString());
 }

Future getToken() async {
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 sharedPreferences.reload();
 String value = sharedPreferences.getString("my_token");
 print("your token: $value");
 return value;
 }
```

Try `flutter clean` before run the app.